# How to add TIMESTAMPDIFF to SqlSoup query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlsoup

I have a reporting program running and using SqlSoup and have the entire query generated now by SqlSoup calls except for the MySqL Function `TIMESTAMPDIFF`.

The actual SQL phrase should be

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(PERIOD, start_time, end_time) <= 60
```

I tried

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func
```

and a where-clause phrase (with `rc` a reference to the database and table)

```
where = and_(where, func.TIMESTAMPDIFF('PERIOD',rc.start_time,rc.end_time) <= 60)
```

This compiles, but with logging on it shows the `PERIOD` as `%s` and then a parameter `PERIOD`
below, which does not seem to work.

Any ideas for doing this with SqlSoup?

Answer (score 5):

`sqlalchemy.text()` is your friend in this case :-)

Try:

```
sqlalchemy.func.TIMESTAMPDIFF(sqlalchemy.text('PERIOD'),rc.start_time,rc.end_time) <= 60)
```